# How to implement custom sort on property inside .class file in Java 7

Tags: java, sorting

I am required to sort `Student` objects on the basis of their `name`. Please note there is no implementation of `compareTo()` in the `Student` class, simple getters and setters only and the class itself is part of `school.jar` which is I am using in my education portal project. How do I access those fields, I can introduce base class for the same but the Student class marked as `final`.

Is this use case technically feasible or not? If so, how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to modify the `Student` class - you can introduce your own [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```java
public class StudentNameComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
    @Override
    int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```java
Collections.sort(listOfStudents, new StudentNameComparator());
```

**EDIT:**
Mandatory comment: Java 8 (or later) would allow for some syntactic sugar around this (such as `Comparator.comparing(Student::getName)`), but the requirement was to use Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> a.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getName()));
```

Comment: Java 7 doesn't have lambdas, though